# Android Draw a line on screen and remove it after clicking a button on screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development in my application i want to draw the line on finger move and want to remove all the lines draw by me with a  button click which is provided on the screen.
 I am able to draw the line but i am not able to remove the lines and the lines are also not smooth.

Comment: What are you drawing on? A custom view? SurfaceView? Your question is VERY vague, you will not get a response unless you provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class to represent your lines, for example:

```
public class Line{
    public float startX;
    public float startY;
    public float endX;
    public float endY;
    public int colour;
    private Paint paint;
    ...
    ...

    public Line(float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY, int colour){
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.endX = endX;
        this.endY = endY;
        this.paint = new Paint();
        this.paint.setColor(colour);
        // look at the antialias and dither options for paint to create a smooth line
        ...
        ...
    }

    public draw(Canvas canvas){
       canvas.drawLine(this.startX, this.startY, this.endX, this.endY, paint);
    }

}
```

Then in your activity, create a list of Line objects, e.g. ArrayList lines;

In your touch event, instead of drawing a line, add a new line to the list.  Then, in your onDraw method, something like this:

```
 for(Line line:lines){
     line.draw(canvas);
 }
```

Finally, in your button click, remove the line object from your lines list.

Good luck!